# Vagrant with Virtualbox on WSL unable to access Windows environment

Tags: windows, vagrant, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have successfully followed steps on vagrant website to setup vagrant on WSL with VirtualBox including setting the windows path and all. but as soon as I try to run

```
sudo vagrant something up
```

it throws the following error

Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:

Vagrant is unable to use the VirtualBox provider from the Windows Subsystem for
Linux without access to the Windows environment. Enabling this access must be
done with caution and an understanding of the implications. For more information
on enabling Windows access and using VirtualBox from the Windows Subsystem for
Linux, please refer to the Vagrant documentation:

Host OS

Edition: Windows 10 Home Single Language
Version: 20H2
OS Build: 19042.870

Ubuntu WSL
Description: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Did you start WSL as the admin user?

Comment: tried running it with both administrative and non-administrative mode but eventually it fails. @RamanSailopal

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is caused when `VAGRANT_WSL_ENABLE_WINDOWS_ACCESS` environment variable is not set.

1. First Export Environment Variables

```
  export VAGRANT_WSL_ENABLE_WINDOWS_ACCESS="1"
```

```
 export PATH="${PATH}:/mnt/c/Program Files/Oracle/VirtualBox"
```

2. Run Vagrant using following commands

```
  vagrant up something
```

if you want to run it as sudo

```
 sudo -E vagrant up something
```

"E" flag preserves the environment variables while using sudo. if this flag is not used the exported environment variables will not be avalaible.